# Avoid incorrect wrapping of some words in RTL languages (Farsi, Arabic)

Tags: css, html, right-to-left

In Farsi, Arabic and some other RTL languages, letters are connected to each other (e.g. سیب), but not always (e.g. می شود). The problem this causes is that sometimes the whitespace will cause half a word to wrap over to the next line.

[image: Example of incorrect wrapping]

This is totally incorrect, but I don't want to disable the whole wrapping style of the paragraph. In Microsoft Word, this problem is dealt by pressing `ctrl+shift+space`. This enters a different white space between the letters that doesn't wrap. How would I achieve something similar in HTML and CSS?

Here's a jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/gb0p72b2/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) character. In MS Word, `ctrl+shift+space` inserts a non-breaking space character. To do that in HTML use this `&nbsp;` instead of the normal white-space. Check out the JSFiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/6k0p9h5k/

Comment: great! I'm sure I have seen this before. Is this the only use for`&nbsp;`?

Comment: Some lazy people use it to add margin or space between HTML elements instead of using CSS padding or margin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without a real arabic page to test on, but CSS `word-wrap: normal` on the `li` elements might help.